# python if statement to check a column for a value and do a command

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, append, tuples

```
for z in range(0,countD.shape[0]):
    if countD[z,0] in background_low1[:,0]:
        background_lowCountD.append(countD[z,:])
    else:
        background_goodCountD.append(countD[z,:])
```

I'm using the above code and getting a "list indices must be integers, not tuple" error message. I have two uneven arrays (CountD and background_low1), If a value is present in column 0 of both arrays at any row level I want to move that row to a new array, if its only present in 1 I want that row moved to a second new array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error message because lists are unidimensional (in theory). But since a list can contain another list, you can create a multidimensional list. Now accessing an element of a list is done using an index (which must be an integer) between brackets. When dealing with multidimensional lists, just use multiple brackets one after the other :

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = [1,2,a]
>>> print b[2]
>>> ['a','b','c']
>>> print b[2][0]
>>> 'a'
```

So, to answer your question, try something like this :

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],
         [5,6,7,8],
         [9,10,11,12]]
list2 = [[1,4,5,6],
         [7,6,7,8],
         [9,1,2,3]]

newList = []
otherList = []

#you need to make sure both lists are the same size
if len(list1) == len(list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i][0] == list2[i][0]:
            newList.append(list1[i])
        else:
            otherList.append(list1[i])

#the lists should now look like this
>>> print newList
>>> [[1,2,3,4],[9,10,11,12]]
>>> print otherList
>>> [[5,6,7,8]]
```

Comment: These are 2 2D arrays. the lists are the same size in only one direction (one is (3,34) the other is (20,34)),

Comment: All you need to make sure is that the list you are iterating over is not bigger than the one you are comparing with. You don't want to get an IndexError : list index out of range.

Comment: nevermind! my code works, I was appending to a list earlier in the program that I np.reshaped into an appropriately sized array but called the un-reshaped one. Thanks anyway for the help